# Java - Jtable Color

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecellrenderer

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;
import java.awt.*;

public class Fenetre extends JFrame implements TableCellRenderer {
    private static TableCellRenderer tcr;

    public Fenetre(TableCellRenderer tcr){
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setTitle("Liste des PC de la DTARS");
        this.setSize(500, 250);

        Object[][] data = {
                {"nomPc", "PC Fixe", "xxxx","OK","24"},
                {"nomPc", "PC Fixe", "xxxx","OK","24"},
                {"nomPc", "PC Fixe", "xxxx","A REMPLACER","24"},
                {"nomPc", "PC Fixe", "xxxx","A REMPLACER","24"},
                {"nomPc", "PC Portable", "xxxx","OK","NA"},
                {"nomPc", "PC Portable", "xxxx","OK","NA"},
                {"nomPc", "PC Fixe", "xxxx","OK","24"},
                {"nomPc", "PC Fixe", "xxxx","OK","24"},
                {"nomPc", "PC Fixe", "xxxx","OK","24"},
                {"nomPc", "PC Fixe", "xxxx","OK","24"},
                {"nomPc", "PC Fixe", "xxxx","OK","24"},
                {"nomPc", "PC Fixe", "xxxx","OK","24"},

        };

         String  title[] = {"Nom Machine", "Type", "Utilisateur","Etat","Ecran"};
        JTable tableau = new JTable(data, title);
        //tableau.setBackground(Color.cyan);
        DefaultTableCellRenderer rightRenderer = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();
        rightRenderer.setHorizontalAlignment(DefaultTableCellRenderer.CENTER);
        tableau.getColumn("Type").setCellRenderer( rightRenderer );
        tableau.getColumn("Utilisateur").setCellRenderer( rightRenderer );
        tableau.getColumn("Etat").setCellRenderer( rightRenderer );
        tableau.getColumn("Ecran").setCellRenderer( rightRenderer );
        tableau.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
        this.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(tableau));

    }

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        Component comp = this.tcr.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
        if ((row & 1) == 0) { // Ligne paire
            comp.setBackground(Color.RED);
        } else { // Ligne impaire
            comp.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        }
        return comp;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Fenetre fen = new Fenetre(tcr);
        fen.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

I'm fighting with the above code. Could you please explain to me what is wrong and how to resolve the lines not changing color.

Answer (score 5):

There are two problems with your code:

1. You set a new `DefaultTableCellRenderer` to the table's columns
   instead of `this`. Note that your `Fenetre` class is the one overriding
   `getTableCellRendererComponent(...)` method in order to change cells
   background color.
2. Your `getTableCellRendererComponent(...)` implementation delagates
   the job to create a renderer component to `tcr` class member, which
   is a `TableCellRenderer` and is not initialized. So you'll get a
   `NullPointerException`

How to solve it?

Just provide a correct `TableCellRenderer` implementation. I wouldn't make the class implement the interface directly, I'd get rid of `tcr` class member and I'd provide a `DefaultTableCellRenderer` overriding `getTableCellRendererComponent(...)` like this:

```
DefaultTableCellRenderer renderer = new DefaultTableCellRenderer() {
    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        Component comp = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
        if ((row % 2) == 0) { // Ligne paire
            comp.setBackground(Color.RED);
        } else { // Ligne impaire
            comp.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        }
        return comp;
    }
};

renderer.setHorizontalAlignment(DefaultTableCellRenderer.CENTER);

tableau.getColumn("Type").setCellRenderer(renderer);
tableau.getColumn("Utilisateur").setCellRenderer(renderer);
tableau.getColumn("Etat").setCellRenderer(renderer);
tableau.getColumn("Ecran").setCellRenderer(renderer);
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason your solution is not working is that there is actually no connection between the `JTable` that you create and your `Fenetre` object in its capacity as a `TableCellRenderer`. That means your method is never actually called.

But `TableCellRenderer` is not really meant to be used like this. It is meant to provide the component for other rendering methods to be used. A better approach would be to override the `prepareRenderer()` method. That method is given the (default) `TableCellRenderer`, can take the component from it, and then give it the color it wants.

[Here](http://blog.marcnuri.com/blog/default/2007/03/15/JTable-Row-Alternate-Row-Background) is Marc Nuri's implementation of exactly what you are asking for - alternate rows in alternating colors.

Note that he is avoiding coloring the currently selected row by checking if its current background is the selection background. I think a better approach is to query the selection (and also checking `isPaintingForPrint()`). So my suggestion for your case is to replace the line:

```
    JTable tableau = new JTable(data, title);
```

with:

```
   JTable table = new JTable(data,title){
        public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int column){
            Component returnComp = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column);

            if ( ! isRowSelected(row) || isPaintingForPrint()){
                Color bg = (row % 2 == 0 ? Color.RED : Color.BLUE );
                returnComp.setBackground(bg);
            }
            return returnComp;
        }
    };
```

Comment: plus one for prepareRenderer